# Java FX 8 CSS ClassCastException

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

In my CSS I have the following definition:

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-background;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}
```

Both "variables" are defined like this:

```
.root {
    -fx-background: derive(#bbb, 25%);
    -fx-text-background-color: ladder(-fx-background, #bbb 10%, etc...);
}
```

On **Java8 u31** as soon as I open a list view I get the following warning in my console:

> javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
>   WARNING: Caught 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javafx.scene.paint.Paint' while converting value for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.list-cell' in stylesheet [...]

When Im actually changing the definition in the css to *-fx-background-test* instead of *-fx-background* and replace it also in the *.list-cell* it works without any warning. So my first guess would be that the naming of -fx-background is a problem. But I got a lot of other stylings which are using the same definition and I dont receive warnings at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the short code you show, it works for me. Do you modify `-fx-background` in other css rules?

Comment: Well, other css styles are using it like  -fx-background: -fx-background; But apart from that, no.

Comment: Do you mean ` -fx-background-color: -fx-background;`, right?

Comment: Well, I can't tell if you don't show more code... `fx-background` is used in many rules in modena.css. Usually the css warnings come for wrong values on the modena side, not on your css.

Comment: I see. Well, I found out, that there are a lot of changes in the modena.css directly instead of overriding, so there is probably an error. Thank you for your help =)